# Cant login to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, privileges, mysqladmin

phpMyAdmin will not accept any passwords. It just gives the error "Cannot log in to MySql Server".

I can access MySQL from the terminal using `mysql -u root -p`.  It asks for the password I enter it and I am in. I get the `mysql> prompt`.

I have tried every fix on the internet, too long to put all the fixes I tried here. I have been at this all day. Its driving me crazy!

When I try to execute the

```
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But it just says access denied to @localhost.

Comment: Maybe myphpadmin nos not configured properly

Comment: it is.  and to those who gave me a -2 for this question.  you are all so kind.  You know we are all programmers.  We should look out for each other and help each other out.  Not stick your nose up at others for asking a question and put them down

Comment: Please Show the phpmyadmin config.

Comment: Thanks Jens.  This was my latest...

<?php
$i=0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'mypassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase']        = 'true';
?>

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information.  You may believe myphpadmin is configured right, but you've provided no real information about what your configuration is.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  which other file should I be looking at for configs besides the config.inc.php

Comment: I wanted to solve this issue without installing MAMP.  But after many, many hours with no resolution, I just installed Mamp and now I am in myphpadmin.  Thank you to Jenns and Rob for helping out.  :)

Comment: I have had this as well. I solved it by using GRANT.

Answer (score 0):

This may help , I forgot my localhost password (MAMP) and this helped me reset the whole localhost :

https://superuser.com/questions/123275/how-do-i-reset-my-root-password-on-mysql-on-a-mac -> bottom answer

Comment: Thanks Badina.  You Rock!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you mean can't login at the login screen when you type localhost/phpmyadmin in the browser search bar.. and if this is the case then this is what worked for me

I created a user for the database by first typing

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
CREATE USER 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'USER'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then restarted the mysql service

Afterwards I was able to login with the user specified in the previous commands